# Cannot create python virtual environments or use pip in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, python3, pip

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. When I try `python3 -m venv env`, I get:

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available. On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.
 
    apt install python3.8-venv
 
You may need to use sudo with that command. After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.
 
Failing command: ['/home/ubuntu/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip',
'--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

Then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.8-venv
```

and got this output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.8-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only
available from another source

E: Package 'python3.8-venv' has no installation candidate
```

If that package is not available any more, I want to know how can I be able to create a virtual environment (the package `python3-pip` is also missing, so `pip` is also not available).

The only way I could create a virtual environment is using `conda`, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: Have you messed with your Python installation? Perhaps tried changing your Python version or something?

Comment: no it is a live cd with no changes to the system

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

I also searched far and wide when I encountered this problem on my system (Ubuntu 22.04), and none of the suggested solutions worked for me, including:

- Running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` beforehand
- Using `pip` in any form (same error as you had)
- [Exporting and reconfiguring locales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539571)

The solution in my case was to (re-)enable the Ubuntu universe repository to be able to install `python3-venv` and related packages, as this was disabled on my machine.

In Ubuntu, this can be done by running the `Software & Updates` tool, which can also be opened by running:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

in the terminal, and then making sure the `Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)` box is ticked (at least in Ubuntu 22.04).

It should prompt you to refresh, after which you can run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install python3-venv`.

I hope this helps.